# How can I insert Drop-down Value and Drop-down Name in two different column respactively

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have table result in result having column `Exam_Id` and `Class_id`.

These two values I am taking from `examid` drop-down list like below code:

```
<select name="examid" class="form-control" style="width:15%">
    <option>Select</option>
    <?php
        $q = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Exam_ID, Class_ID FROM exam");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
        {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['Class_ID'] ?>"><?php echo $row['Exam_ID']; ?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

I want to insert `Class_Id` and `Exam_id` in different different column respectively in result table. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: Now u will get only Class_id.if u need to get Exam_id you should add it with option value like  <option Value="<?php echo $row['Class_ID'] ?>_<?php echo $row['Exam_ID']; ?><" ><?php echo $row['Exam_ID']; ?></option>

Comment: @Shanukk but how it add im my table will $query="INSERT INTO `result` (Marks_ID,Exam_ID, Class_ID) VALUES ('$Result_id','$ExamID','$Class_ID)";

Comment: can you please show me your POST page?

Comment: $subject_name = $_POST['subject_name'];
$ExamID = $_POST['examid'];
$RollNo =  $_POST['rollno'];
$Class_ID = $_POST['examid'];

Answer (score 0):

You can get value and text of dropdown differently using jquery.
Try below code.

For exam id use

```
$('select[name=examid] option:selected').text();
```

For class id use

```
$('select[name=examid]').val();
```

Comment: but how will take in POST variable

Comment: Class id you will get in POST Array.

Comment: For exam_id make hidden field as

Comment: but i want both value should insert